# Why typescript doesn't accept React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react ts app I have this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleEscKeyPress = (
      event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { isComposing: boolean }
    ) => {
      if (event.isComposing || event.key === 'Escape') {
        onClose();
        return;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress!);
    };
  }, []);
```

IDE highlights  document.addEventListener('keydown', ***handleEscKeyPress***); and messages:

```
const handleEscKeyPress: (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & {
    isComposing: boolean;
}) => void
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown", listener: (this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & {    isComposing: boolean;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'KeyboardEvent' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { isComposing: boolean; }'.
          Type 'KeyboardEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>': locale, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & {    isComposing: boolean;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & {    isComposing: boolean;}) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { isComposing: boolean; }'.
            Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, code, and 15 more.ts(2769)
```

What type should I assign for event to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A React keyboard event is not the same as a keyboard event directly from the browser. `document.addEventListener` does not accept a callback that uses a React event.

You cannot specify that the event is on an `HTMLInputElement` either - that's not the only element the `keydown` event can be fired on. Use just `KeyboardEvent`.

Because `isComposing` is already a property typed on the native `KeyboardEvent`, you can leave it off entirely.

```
const handleEscKeyPress = (
    event: KeyboardEvent
) => {
```

Also, because the function will always be defined:

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress!);
```

the non-null assertion is superfluous:

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have same error with options:
* event: React.KeyboardEvent 
* event: React.KeyboardEvent & { isComposing: boolean }

Comment: What line has that error? I can't reproduce what you're describing. There should be no references to `React.KeyboardEvent` anymore. Are you sure you removed it as the answer shows?

Comment: Error on same line "document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress!);"  (with or without "!")

Answer (score -1):

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';
```

const handleKeyPress = (e: KeyboardEvent && { isComposing: boolean }) => {
// do stuff
};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).